# Using django-bootstrap4 + django_icons + my custom css files

Tags: css, django

Can someone provide any steps to use django-bootstrap4 and django_icons python packages with my own css files for a project the static folder of my django app? This prevent any confusions between python packages and .css when styling the django template html file.

Comment: Is the question still too broad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base template is the most basic template that you extend on every page of your website.

Here is a simple example for you:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
         content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
       <title>{{ title }}</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:700,900" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static('main.css') }}">
       {% block css %}

       {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
    <!— Render content —>
        <div class="container">
            {% include 'common/header.html '%}
            {% include 'common/navbar.html '%}
            {% block content %}

            {% endblock %}
            {% include 'common/footer.html' %}
        </div>
    <script src="{{ static('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    {% block js %}
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
  </html>
```

in your html file you will just need to extend the base.html file then, all your custom css, html components and custom js file will be placed where you declared the block in your base.html file.
For example :

```
{% block css%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static('main.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

that means in your html file, all of your css from base.html will be loaded first, then your custom css files will be loaded.